# Accidentally locked out the only logged in admin user

Tags: windows-10, administrator

I purchased a new Lenovo ThinkBook, and I created a new user account, and accidentally disabled the current logged in user account. When I logged in as the new user, to my horror, I discovered that I forgot to make the new user as member of Administrators group and the previous user which I disabled was in fact the member of Administrators group. Windows did not give any warning that I am disabling the only active administrator of the system.

Now I am unable to make myself administrator.

What is the solution now? How can I access my laptop as an administrator.
I am using Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Try accessing the built in administrator account to fix your issue:   https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/enable-built-in-administrator-windows-10-recovery-options-advanced/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed some of the steps in that article, and then in one of the screens, I chose to restore my system to an earlier Restore Point. This worked for me. Now the admin user which I disabled, is restored as admin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try accessing the built in administrator account to fix your issue:

In the article referenced below, there is a section that applies to you (machine will start, just not as admin).

**Enabling the built-in administrator (“Administrator”) account** can be done through Windows Recovery Environment (aka “Recovery Options”) if you cannot log in to your user account.

Log in to Advanced Recovery Options (Windows RE)

1. From the sign-in screen in Windows 10/11, press and hold the SHIFT key on the keyboard.
2. With the SHIFT key still pressed, click the Power button and then click Restart.
3. In the Recovery Options menu, click Troubleshoot, and then click on Advanced Options

[Recover built in admin](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/enable-built-in-administrator-windows-10-recovery-options-advanced/)

You can find options, among them, to restore to an earlier point. The restore point helped you in this case.